# Could the CoreBluetooth framework be used to connect to non-Apple devices?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Could CoreBluetooth be used to connect a Mac/iPhone to non-Apple devices, e.g., an arbitrary Bluetooth LE device and talk with it? I'm asking because I'm having a hard time connecting my Mac running Yosemite to my BLE module.

Does anyone know of a snippet that does this? I must be missing something simple.

Thanks

Comment: As long as the BLE devices supports the GATT profile (this is the most common profile for BLE peripherals) you can connect to it.  Perhaps you can show the code you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The Core Bluetooth API on an iPhone or Mac that includes built-in BLE hardware can be used to connect to most any standard BLE peripheral that is advertising and that has services and characteristics that follow the BLE standard.

(I've used Core Bluetooth on a MacBook Air and an iPhone to connect to several Arduino BLE devices (including the LightBlue Bean), TI SensorTags, heart monitors, stride sensors, and etc., none of them made by Apple.)